# Problem with changing format of date and time in R

Tags: r, posixct, strptime, as.date, posixlt

I am having a problem with date & time format in R.

My R code is having the format: "%Y%m%d %H%M%OS". For example: "20170929 20:59:56.149"

Time in my case is character variable.

I am trying to write a R code where type of format will be converted into the format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"

```
(data <- strptime(data$time, 
                    format = "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%OS", 
                    tz = "GMT"))
```

or for example

```
data$time <- as.POSIXct(data$time, format = "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%OS")
```

But, I am getting NA. What could this be caused by? Do you have any idea how to fix it? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The `format` parameter tells the function how to parse the date... When you specify "%Y-%m-%d" - the function looks for those dashes ("-") which do not exist in the example string you gave (with "20170929" your format parameter should be "%Y%m%d"). The same goes for your time parsing.

Comment: The core misunderstanding you have, I think, is that the functions `as.Date` or `as. POSIXct` do not simply change the format of a date... they actually try to convert a type (in your case, a character/string) into the `date` or `POSIXct` type. The format parameter tells this conversion function how to interpret the string. Once you have your data represented as a `POSIXct` type, you can then use a different function, `format`, to produce a new string with some desired form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual `help(strftime)`:
*If the specified time is invalid (for example ‘"2010-02-30 08:00"’) all the components of the result are ‘NA’.*

Furthermore, if you want to manipulate your output format of a date you need the date stored as a Date-class (illustration of @izyda's comments).

First, reformat your date to make it easier to manipulate:

```
data <- "20170929 20:59:56.149"
dat_new <- paste( paste( substr(data, 1, 4), 
   substr(data, 5, 6), substr(data, 7, 8), sep="-" ), 
   substr(data, 10,nchar(data)) )
dat_new
[1] "2017-09-29 20:59:56.149"
```

Then, change the class to Date:

```
dat_cor <- as.POSIXct( dat_new, tz="GMT" )
dat_cor
[1] "2017-09-29 20:59:56 GMT"
class(dat_new)
[1] "character"
class(dat_cor)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Finally, choose your output format:

```
strftime( dat_cor, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS3", tz="GMT" )
[1] "09/29/2017 20:59:56.148"
# or
strftime( dat_cor, format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%OS3", tz="GMT" )
[1] "2017-29-09 20:59:56.148"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @izyda has already cleared up the confusion. The format that you include in `strptime` is the format of the data that you have, so in this case you use -

```
x <- "20170929 20:59:56.149"
strptime(x, format = "%Y%m%d  %H:%M:%OS", tz = "GMT")
#[1] "2017-09-29 20:59:56 GMT"
```

The same can be applied to `as.POSIXct`.

Alternatively, if you are confused by different formats or tired of referring to `?strptime` you can use `lubridate` package. In this case, function `ymd_hms` would help.

```
lubridate::ymd_hms(x)
#[1] "2017-09-29 20:59:56 UTC"
```